# onmousemove using 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, events, handler

I probably got a quite simple question. I generate some images using javascript. when i click on such an image and move the cursor the image should follow until i click again.
That is my solution:

I create the img and connect it with an "onclick" event handler:

```
img.onclick = prepare_pic_move(img);
```

This kind of handler starts the "onmousemove" handler:

```
  function prepare_pic_move(img) {
img.onmousemove = pic_move(ev, img);
  }
```

That function should finally move the picture:

```
  function pic_move(ev, img) {
    img.style.left = ev.ClientX;
    img.style.top = ev.ClientY;
  }
```

It does not work and the firefox bug console says that ev is not defined.
I think the problem is that i have to use two parameters at the pic_move function.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass `ev` to function prepare_pic_move, try this way

```
img.onclick = function (ev) { prepare_pic_move(ev, img); };
```

P.S. I don't think you need to pass img as a parameter, and ClientX is not cross browser.

```
img.onclick = function (ev) {
    img.style.left = ev.ClientX;
    img.style.top = ev.ClientY;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass in argument img as you can get it through ev.srcElement. So both of your methods need only one argument. In fact the argument you named img in your first method is actually your ev if you wire your onclick event using img.onclick=prepare_pic_move; Then it will be called with the ev object you need as first argument (which you can rename from img to ev)

Answer (score 0):

`prepare_pic_move` should return an event handler. It is currently returning `undefined` instead.

```
function prepare_pic_move(img) {
    return function(evt){
        img.onmousemove = pic_move(ev, img);
    };
}
```